# Android:Cordova I need capture photo portrait from camera

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap

I need set portrait photo from camera.

I using Android Cordova and camera plugin

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, 
{
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    allowEdit: true,
    correctOrientation: true,
});
```